# Loss is not decreasing

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am implementing a DNN with, but problem is that the loss is high and not decrease after all Iterations. The lables shape is torch.Size([1124823]), The feat size is torch.Size([1124823, 13]), X train shape torch.Size([719886, 13]), X test shape torch.Size([224965, 13]), X val shape torch.Size([179972, 13]), y train shape torch.Size([719886]), y train shape torch.Size([719886]), y val shape torch.Size([179972])

My Dataloader was implemented as follows:

```py
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feat, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

    train = data_utils.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
    train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=1000, shuffle=True)

    test = data_utils.TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)
    test_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(test, batch_size=1000, shuffle=False)

input_size = 13
hidden1_size = 13
hidden2_size = 64
hidden3_size = 128
hidden4_size = 256
hidden5_size = 1024
output_size = 3989

class DNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, hidden3_size, hidden4_size, hidden5_size, output_size):
        super(DNN, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden1_size)
        self.drp1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.tan1 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden1_size, hidden2_size)
        self.drp2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.tan2 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden2_size, hidden3_size)
        self.drp3 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.tan3 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden3_size, hidden4_size)
        self.drp4 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.tan4 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(hidden4_size, hidden5_size)
        self.drp5 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
        self.tan5 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(hidden5_size, output_size)
        self.tan6 = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.drp1(out)
        out = self.relu1(out)
        out = self.tan1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.drp2(out)
        out = self.relu2(out)
        out = self.tan2(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        out = self.drp3(out)
        out = self.relu3(out)
        out = self.tan3(out)
        out = self.fc4(out)
        out = self.drp4(out)
        out = self.relu4(out)
        out = self.tan4(out)
        out = self.fc5(out)
        out = self.drp5(out)
        out = self.relu5(out)
        out = self.tan5(out)
        out = self.fc6(out)
        out = self.tan6(out)
        return out
batch_size = 10
n_iterations = 50
no_eps = n_iterations / (13 / batch_size)
no_epochs = int(no_eps)
model = DNN(input_size, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, hidden3_size, hidden4_size, hidden5_size, output_size)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
learning_rate = 0.0001
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

iter = 0
for epoch in range(no_epochs):
    for i, (X_train, y_train) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(Variable(X_train))
        loss = criterion(outputs, Variable(y_train))
        print('Iter %d --> loss %f' % (i, loss.item()))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    print('test')
    for X_test, y_test in test_loader:
        outputs = model(Variable(X_test))
        pred = outputs.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
        total += y_test.size(0)
        correct += (pred.squeeze() == y_test).sum()  # pred.eq(y_test.view_as(pre  d)).sum().item()

    accuracy = 100 * correct / total

    print('Iteration: {}.  Accuracy: {}'.format(epoch, accuracy))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loss is an `nn.CrossEntropy()`. This criterion must get logits as input and you're giving `nn.Tanh()`.

I don't know how you're loading your data (you didn't show it), but it suggests you're using a `Dataloader`. So, you don't need to use `Variable`. You can send the tensor like: `model(X_train)` and `criterion(outputs, y_train)`. As you have a `batch_size` variable, it suggests you're using batch_size, right? So, this line:

```
print('Iter %d --> loss %f' % (i, loss.item()))
```

Is computing the loss only for one batch. It's more realistic to compute it to the epoch. You need to accumulate the loss and then print the average, for ex:

```py
acc_loss = 0
for x, y, in data_loader:
  acc_loss += loss.item()
print("Loss:", acc_loss/len(data_loader))
```

Comment: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feat, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=1) X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

Create a data loader for my features and labels
train = data_utils.TensorDataset(feat, labels) train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=500, shuffle=True)

test = data_utils.TensorDataset(feat, labels) test_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(test, batch_size=500, shuffle=False)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand anything!

Comment: sorry, can you see my answer below? The code is well formatted

Comment: Can you have a look on my data loader I put it in the question again